# Why does implementing this protocol return an error?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to implement a protocol in Objective C.

```
@implementation UsingViewsViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad
    ...
```

However, XCode issues an error: "Unexpected identifier or '('".

The code compiles, however, if I take out `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`.

Why is it erring with the protocol notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your @interface and @implementation mixed up. Try:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UIViewAlertDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation MyClass
...
@end
```

Note that the @interface belongs in the header file, and the @implementation belongs in the .m file.

Answer (score 1):

Put `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in your header (.h file)

```
@interface UsingViewsViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate> {
```

Your implementation (.m) should start that way:

```
@implementation UsingViewsViewController
```